# What is correct type for getDate in Cursor?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I dont know what is correct code to get date in the cursor as the error said:

> Cannot resolve constructor "Website(int, java.util.String,
>   java.util.String)"

My constructor is:

```
public Website(int id, Date stamped, String url, String content){
        this._id = id;
        this._stamped = stamped;
        this._url = url;
        this._content = content;
    }
```

The cursor is:

```
Website getWebsite(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_WEBSITE, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                            KEY_STAMPED, KEY_URL, KEY_CONTENT }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            Website website = new Website(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getDate(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            // return contact
            return website;
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you can store `Date` objects. Store your date as a String instead and then convert it to Date.

Comment: Best way to do it is by storing it as a unix timestamp, especially if there's a chance you're dealing with time zones.